# How to cancel subscribe for a particular subscribe when POST requests are happening for an array of elements

Tags: angular

I'm creating a file up-loader component in Angular 14.

**Requirement:**
User should be able to cancel an upload which is taking longer than expected.

**Achieved:**

1. UI and basic logic I've done already.
2. All dragged and dropped files are stored in an array `droppedFilesArray`.

**My thought process:**

I thought If I run `map` on `droppedFilesArray` and for each item I will span a dedicated http post request. and I'll show a cross symbol next to file name in UI till i receive a response from post. This way I'll be able to `unsubscribe` on click of that cross icon if that particular upload is taking longer than expected. Rest of the uploads will continue normally.

This is was my idea:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
  uploadFiles() {
    this.myfiles.forEach((file, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.droppedFileArray[i].fileEntry.file((file: File) => {
          if (this.isFileSizeAllowed(file.size)) {
            if (this.files.length < 6) {
              this.fileFound = true;
              const formData = new FormData();
              formData.append('excel', file);
              const headers = new HttpHeaders({
                'x-request-id': 'file_upload_' + new Date().getTime(),
              });
              this.req[i] = this.http
                .post(
                  'http://localhost:8090/core-services/file-upload/upload',
                  formData,
                  {
                    headers: headers,
                    responseType: 'json',
                  }
                )
                .pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)))
                .subscribe((res: any) => {
                  this.hasError = false;
                  this.filesLoaded = true;
                  this.fileUploading = false;
                  this.showMessage();
                });
            } else {
              this.messageService.add({
                  // 'File limit exceeded. Cannot upload more than 5 files at a time.',
              });
            }
          } else {
            this.messageService.add({
                //  'Max size of a file allowed is 1mb, files with size more than 1mb are discarded.',
            });
          }
        });
      }, i * 4000);
    });
  }
```

Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r7mrrm

The problem is that I'm getting the error `this.req` is not defined`. Also please help me with the better logic if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
req : Array<Subscription> =[];
```

...

```
this.req[i] =  this.http
                .post(
                  'http://localhost:8090/core-services/file-upload/upload',
                  formData,
                  {
                    headers: headers,
                    responseType: 'json',
                  }
                )
                .pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)))
                .subscribe((res: any) => {
                  this.hasError = false;
                  this.filesLoaded = true;
                  this.fileUploading = false;
                  this.showMessage();
                });
```

...
You could stop subscription and http request by:

```
this.req[i].unsubscribe();
```